# Configuring Scala 2.11 with Play 2.5.4

Tags: playframework

As far as my knowledge, Play 2.5.4 needs scala 2.11 or higher.

My Play seems to read from 'project\target\scala-2.10\sbt-0.13\resource_managed\main\sbt\sbt.builds,'

Why is it reading scala 2.10 when i have 2.11 installed?

Can someone please help?

Help with telling play that it has to use Scala 2.11 and not 2.10.

```
error:
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 6 Jul, 2016 2:20:54 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file `build.sbt` you should add the line:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Comment: There are only 3 files in the project directory. Build.scala, plugins.sbt and build.properties.  Where do I add scalaVersion key value ? Please suggest.

Comment: use build.properties for build too (sbt) version, plugins to add plugins, typically I use Versions.scala to keep versions and a Dependencies.scala to keep dependencies  (just an object  with lazy val ModuleID sequence of dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Inside build.scala add scalaVersion= "2.11.8"